# Is there a way in tcl to replace the tcl process with the process of a command?

Tags: tcl

I would like to do the equivalent of `exec` in `sh`, or `execve(2)`, just transfer control from tcl to a called command and never return, so that any signals sent to what used to be the tcl process go directly to the called command, stdout of the called command is the stdout of what used to be the tcl process, etc.

I have looked around in the manuals, but haven't found an obvious way to do this in tcl.

I'm not talking about tcl's `exec`, which keeps tcl running, creates a subprocess and captures its output, then resumes control flow in the tcl process.

Comment: If I wanted to do something that system specific (i.e. unix-like specific) I would probably just write a small extension to do all the low level system programming it takes to make that happen smoothly. And by "transfer control ... to a called command" I presume you mean transfer to an executable and not a Tcl command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built into Tcl itself at the moment, but the [TclX extension](https://github.com/flightaware/tclx) includes a command, [`execl`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tclx8.2/TclX.n.html#lbAF), which can do exactly what you want.

```
package require TclX

execl /bin/bash [list -c somescript.sh]
```

Note that doing an `execl` that fails may put the process in an inconsistent state, as some libraries use hooks to detect the underlying system call and close their resources. It depends on exactly what you're doing of course, but since the X11 library is a notable example of this, Tk applications are unsafe to continue the current process with if `execl` fails. (The `fork`/`execl` idiom — or Tcl's standard `exec` — doesn't have the problem, as the problem syscall always happens in a subprocess.)

Comment: Since I can't suggest a one-char-changed edit, I'm making a comment. Did you mean `package require Tclx` (with the lower-case `x`) from the code?